# UIWebView won't reload a new URL in Swift

Tags: ios, uiwebview, swift2

I always used UIWebView without troubles until I wanted to load a new URL. With the code below, the second url will not be loaded for some reason. Can you find why? (The plist has the exceptions for the domains!)

```
    let webview = UIWebView()
    webview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, view.bounds.width, view.bounds.height )
    view.addSubview(webview)

    var url = NSURL (string: "http://google.com")
    var requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!,
        cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData,
        timeoutInterval: 10.0)
    webview.loadRequest(requestObj)
    webview.reload()

    //Wait 5 seconds to load another page
    let time = dispatch_time(dispatch_time_t(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW), 5 * Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC))
    dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

    url = NSURL (string: "http://yahoo.com")
     requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!,
        cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData,
        timeoutInterval: 10.0)

    webview.loadRequest(requestObj)
    webview.reload()
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `webview.loadRequest()` begins loading the webview content.  Calling `webview.reload()` reloads the last request that has finished loading.  Since you're calling reload immediately after loading the request, reload is loading your first request "google.com" again.
Removing the `webview.reload()` calls will load your second request.

Comment: @Duarte Super!  Please accept my answer if it helped you.